# Mismatched Names to Values from lists in written csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write out a CSV file by printing out an output of average readings, maximum readings and outlier readings. I have the readings, but they are not in order. Here is my output when I try to print out outlier readings, printing out the sensor name beforehand. This happens for every reading I try in the functions I have made. I would like it to print from 1 to 25, instead of starting at 22 and then becoming randomized.

```
sensor_22
[5]
sensor_23
[5, 6]
sensor_20
[5, 6, 5]
sensor_21
[5, 6, 5, 1]
sensor_24
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1]
sensor_25
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6]
sensor_9
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8]
sensor_8
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 5]
sensor_3
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 5, 0]
sensor_2
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 5, 0, 6]
sensor_1
[5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 6, 8, 5, 0, 6, 9]...etc
```

The values are mismatched to the sensor name in my [final CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUnbk.png).

Here is some CSV file data. It is a fairly large file.

```
sensor_1,2018-01-02,115
sensor_1,2018-01-03,51
sensor_1,2018-01-04,30
sensor_1,2018-01-05,198
```

Here is my current code. I cannot use any pandas, numpy..etc

```
import csv


options = []
options_readings = {}
max_readings= []
avg_readings = []
outlier_readings = []


with open('sensor_data.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

        for row in reader:
            if row[0] not in options:
                    options.append(row[0])
                    options_readings[row[0]] = []
            sensor_name = row[0]
            datastamp = row[1]
            readings = float(row[2]) 
            options_readings[row[0]].append(readings)

def calculateNumberOfOutlierReadings():
    for option in options_readings:
            print(option)
            readings = options_readings[option]
            count = 0
            for row in readings:
                if(row > 180 or row <0):
                count +=1
            outlier_readings.append(count)
            print(outlier_readings)

def calculateMaxReadings():
    for options in options_readings:
            max_readings.append(max(options_readings[options]))


def calculateAverageReadings():
    for option in options_readings:
        readings = options_readings[option]
        avg_readings.append(sum(readings)/len(readings))  

calculateMaxReadings()
calculateAverageReadings()



calculateNumberOfOutlierReadings()


zip(options, avg_readings, max_readings, outlier_readings)  

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter = ',')
    header = ["Sensor Name", "Average Reading", "Maximum Reading", "Number of Outlier Readings"]
    writer.writerow([i for i in header])

    writer.writerows(zip(options, avg_readings, max_readings, outlier_readings))
```

I believe using options_readings as a dictionary and trying to sort those keys are my issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Any chance you could reduce that to a [mcve]? Only include what is necessary to reproduce the problem? Have you tested your functions? Do they all work as expected? Which part of your solution do you think is the problem?

Comment: I think I have edited it down to that and formatted things to code, let me know if that works.

Comment: You have three functions have you tested them? Do they all work? If not what is wrong with them?

Comment: I have tested them, they work at calculating their respective calculations for each sensor name, the issue is putting those readings in order since they are mismatched like the output above (for outlier readings) back into a csv writer file.

Comment: since I cannot embed images yet, I have posted an image link where it says "final CSV file" where it shows the mismatched output from the terminal output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your solution, sort the data before you write it to a file.

```
....
data = sorted(zip(options, avg_readings, max_readings, outlier_readings)  )

with open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter = ',')
    header = ["Sensor Name", "Average Reading", "Maximum Reading", "Number of Outlier Readings"]
    writer.writerow([i for i in header])

    writer.writerows(data)
```

---

Suggested improvements:
Rewrite the functions so that they return a result. Many (most?) people prefer functions to return value(s) instead of mutating things *external* to the function.

```
def calculateNumberOfOutlierReadings(readings):
    count = 0
    for reading in readings:
        if reading < 0 or reading > 180:
            count += 1
    return count

def calculateMaxReadings(readings):
    return max(readings)

def calculateAverageReadings(readings):
    return sum(readings) / len(readings)
```

Keep all the data from the csv in a dictionary - `{sensor_name:[value,value,...]}`.

```
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for (sensor,date,value) in reader:
        data[sensor].append(float(value))
```

Iterate over the data; perform calcs on each item's values; put the calcs in a tuple using the sensor name for the first item; store the tuple in a list.

```
results = []
for sensor,readings in data.items():
    number_of_outliers = calculateNumberOfOutlierReadings(readings)
    maximum = calculateMaxReadings(readings)
    average = calculateAverageReadings(readings)
    results.append((sensor,average,maximum,number_of_outliers))
```

Sort the results

```
results.sort()
```

---

For a csv that looks like

```
sensor_4,2018-01-05,198
sensor_2,2018-01-02,115
sensor_4,2018-01-03,51
sensor_2,2018-01-04,30
sensor_1,2018-01-02,115
sensor_4,2018-01-04,30
sensor_2,2018-01-05,198
sensor_1,2018-01-04,30
sensor_3,2018-01-04,30
sensor_1,2018-01-05,198
sensor_4,2018-01-02,115
sensor_2,2018-01-05,198
sensor_3,2018-01-02,115
sensor_1,2018-01-03,51
sensor_3,2018-01-03,51
sensor_2,2018-01-03,51
sensor_3,2018-01-05,198
```

`results` ends up being in the order you want:

```
In [16]: results
Out[16]: 
[('sensor_1', 98.5, 198.0, 1),
 ('sensor_2', 118.4, 198.0, 2),
 ('sensor_3', 98.5, 198.0, 1),
 ('sensor_4', 98.5, 198.0, 1)]
```